# What's the difference between odd and even Java updates?

Tags: java, version, oraclejdk

I have JDK 8u60 installed. I checked the [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) today and they have released two versions simultaneously: [8u65](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u65-relnotes-2687063.html) and [8u66](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u66-relnotes-2692847.html). Both are public release versions.

- Why did they release two versions simultaneously?
- What conditions/reasons would make one choose one over the other?

Comment: From Oracle's website: "Java SE 8u65 / 8u66
Java SE 8u65 includes important security fixes. Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE 8 users upgrade to this release. Java SE 8u66 is a patch-set update, including all of 8u65 plus additional features (described in the release notes)." [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Did you check the ReleaseNotes?

Comment: @mnille Yes I did check the notes. When they say 8u66 is a patch-set update, does that mean it's a "better" version? If it is, then why release 8u65?

Comment: Ok, sorry, now I understand your question. I would choose SE 8u66 because 8u66 fixes 15 (+3 from 8u65) bugs and 8u65 just 3 bugs. At least oif the list of fixed bugs is complete...I have to admit this is a bit confusing...

Comment: I added links to both Release Notes. Those notes do *not* explain this mystery.

Comment: @BasilBourque Exactly, which is quite strange. Even more, in the JDK 8u65 release note we can see a section about "**Better group dynamics**" which is missing in the JDK 8u66 note (despite the statement that 8u66 includes some additional features). Otherwise the contents of both notes seem similar.

Comment: I think it is a programming related question because the JDK is for programmers, and for programmers only. Non-programmers wouldn't be concerned with the JDK, they'd be concerned with the JRE.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

From [the download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (**emphasis** added):

> Java SE 8u65 includes important security fixes. Oracle strongly
>   recommends that all Java SE 8 users upgrade to this release. Java SE
>   8u66 is a patch-set update, including all of 8u65 **plus additional
>   features (described in the release notes).**

[Oracle often does this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/cpu-psu-explained-2331472.html). It's all about how you as a customer want to handle the risks.

> Users should only use the corresponding PSU release if they are being 
>   impacted by one of the additional bugs fixed in that version as noted in 
>   the release notes.

8u65 has security fixes and [sets a new security "baseline"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html) for <strike>companies to achieve</strike> [Java 8 applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/family-clsid-140615.html). 8u66 has those same security updates, [plus additional bug fixes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u66-bugfixes-2692105.html). However, even bug fixes can sometimes cause changes to behaviour that present compatibility issues for users. Thus the changes in 8u66 are *optional* (note that the baseline linked above is still 1.8.0_65, and companies that want more stability in their platform might well prefer to only apply the security fixes, which are necessary.

Oracle is certainly not obligated to split their updates in this fashion, but I'm sure some of their most risk-averse customers are glad to have the option.

Comment: Can you cite official documentation for this Answer?

Comment: added some links and extra text

Comment: You must use Java SE 8u65, only use Java SE 8u66 if you need a lot of that fix release.

Comment: @frekele Your comment leaves me still confused.   Why, coming to get a new install, to start a new project, wouldn't I get 8u66, to ensure that I don't end up debugging a known issue?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second part of the question: "What reasons would make you chose one version or the other".  In reading your answer, I can see that you might not want to choose 8u66 if you have an existing project that might suffer change.   But why wouldn't you choose 8u66 for a new one?

Comment: @GreenAsJade sure, if you're starting a brand new Java project, or you have no other Java code to support, you might as well start with the latest update. The difference between the CPU and the PSU is generally extremely small; for almost all cases it will not matter. It is a matter of choosing which risks you prefer: the risks that come with being a little bit behind (known issues), or the risks that come with being on the most recent version (unproven changes / unknown issues). Latest is not necessarily greatest; it depends on your needs.

Comment: For a new project, I'd use 8u66.

Comment: What does 8u71, or any odd/even combination thereafter, have?  8u65 + important security fixes?  Or 8u66 + important security fixes?

Comment: @antak the patches are meant to be a straight progression. In your example 8u71 would include all fixes in 8u66, + other security fixes, + possibly other bug fixes. However, the 8u66 changes will have had longer to "bake" in the real world, by the time of 8u71, and so will have correspondingly less risk.

Answer (score 30):

This is the official [Oracle's answer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/cpu-psu-explained-2331472.html):

> ## Java CPU and PSU Releases Explained
>
> Starting with the release of Java SE 7 Update 71 (Java SE 7u71) in
>   October 2014, Oracle will release a Critical Patch Update (CPU) at the
>   same time as a corresponding Patch Set Update (PSU) for Java SE 7.
>
> ---
>
> #### Which Java version should I choose: the CPU or the PSU?
>
> Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE users upgrade to the
>   latest CPU release available for a release family. Most users should
>   choose the CPU release.
>
> Users should only use the corresponding PSU release if they are being
>   impacted by one of the additional bugs fixed in that version as noted
>   in the release notes.
>
> The subsequent CPU release will contain all of the fixes from the
>   current PSU. For this reason, organizations should test the current
>   PSU in their environment in anticipation of these fixes being included
>   in the next CPU.
>
> #### What is the difference between a Java CPU and PSU release?
>
> Java SE Critical Patch Updates (CPU) contain fixes to security
>   vulnerabilities and critical bug fixes. Oracle strongly recommends
>   that all Java SE users upgrade to the latest CPU releases as they are
>   made available. Java SE CPU releases are odd numbered versions (i.e.
>   7u71, 7u65 – see more on Java SE version numbering schemes here).
>
> Java SE Patch Set Updates (PSU) contain all of fixes in the
>   corresponding CPU, as well as additional non-critical fixes. Java PSU
>   releases should only be used if you are being impacted by one of the
>   additional bugs fixed in that version. The release notes call out the
>   additional fixes available in Java SE PSU releases.
>
> #### Is the cadence of CPU releases changing?
>
> As before, Java SE CPU releases are scheduled for release on the
>   Tuesday closest to the 17th day of January, April, July and October
>   under the normal Oracle Critical Patch Update schedule.
>
> Starting in October 2014 with the release of Java SE 7u71 (CPU) and
>   Java SE 7u72 (PSU), Oracle plans to additionally release a
>   corresponding PSU release along with each CPU release for Java SE 7.
>   PSU releases provide organizations and developers with access to
>   non-critical fixes in addition to the critical fixes contained in the
>   corresponding CPU.

Use u73 unless you know you need a bug fix that's in u74.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing project use 8u65. If you are starting one from scratch use 8u66. I'm installing NetBeans 8.1 so I'm using 8u66 in case NB8.1 code has any of the 15 bugs in 8u65 which are not solved in 8u66.

Answer (score 0):

I found this info on Haven and Hearth:

> u73(-b02) is the public release
>   u74(-b02) is public Bundled Patch Release (contains extra non security related fixes)

I'm thinking you'd only need to download 74, then.

Comment: BPR are different commercial builds, the even Updates are PSU. 1.8.0 u74b02 is public and u74b3x are BPR.